# SQL Join statement return only fisrt row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a 2 tables :

```
**Table Actor**

id_actor

name

surname

**Table Show**

id_show

name

date

time

fk_id_actor
```

Now I want to show all actors which playing in show "Rambo" (name of the Show).

part of my insert sql file :

```
INSERT INTO ACTOR VALUES (1, 'Bill', 'Clinton');

INSERT INTO ACTOR VALUES (2, 'Monika', 'Lewinsky');
.
.
.

INSERT INTO SHOW VALUES (1, 'Rambo', to_date('20.06.2012', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), '20:00 - 21:30', 1);

INSERT INTO SHOW VALUES (2, 'Rambo', to_date('20.06.2012', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), '20:00 - 21:30', 2);
.
.
.
```

And now my sql file which should display all actors in same movie but it display only 1 row (Bill Clinton Rambo) :

```
select actor.name, actor.surname, show.name

from actor

inner join show

on actor.id_actor = show.id_show

where show.name =  'Rambo';
```

output :

```
NAME            SURNAME            NAME                                              
---------------------------------------
Bill            Clinton            Rambo
```

So, where is Monika Lewinsky?

Comment: It seems ok but why actor.id_actor = show.id_show?  Isn't it actor.id_actor = show.fk_id_actor?

Comment: This should not affect the outcome of the rows you have above, but why are you joining on `id_actor = id_show` and not `id_actor = fk_id_actor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need

```
inner join show

 on actor.id_actor = show.fk_id_actor
```

Comment: Although the OP's join is wrong, it actually would still return 2 rows if what is shown above is real --  that is, ids 1,2 in `actor` would still join to ids `1,2` in `show` so 2 rows would come back.

Comment: I did this (actor.id_actor = show.id_show) by guessing, because if I do actor.id_actor = show.fk_id_actor, then return is blank (empty).

Comment: double check your table values. The point of `fk_id_actor` is to associate that record to the actor table. Further, I agree with @Prix, you should have a 3rd table, commonly called a join table, so that you can link any actor(s) to any show(s).